# SD Card maintaining partition map after zero-ing out data

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, sd-card

I have a stubborn SD card that I can't seem to update the partition map on. If I run `diskutil list` I get

```
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *64.5 GB    disk2
   1:                      Linux                         64.5 GB    disk2s1
```

I've previously formatted this SD card for use in a microcomputer, which put a Linux partition on it. I've tried reformatting, but the partition map never changes.

I've also tried zero-ing out the SD card with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=8192` but that also doesn't seem to have an effect.

Does anyone know how else I could completely erase this SD card?

Answer (score -1):

Try using a windows computer and then destroy the partiotion table with either:
Diskpart (a command line application):
[Disk part explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh9ks.png)

Or "MiniTool Partition Wizard Free" which is very easy to use:
[MiniTool Partition Wizard explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlpU5.png)